# another infinite product problem

Tags: infinite-product

Is there a way to simplify the following
$$
1-\prod_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(k+a)^2-1}{(k+a)^2+b^2}
$$
to a single infinite product? Assumptions: $a>0$, $b>0$.

Can the following idea prove useful?
$$
\prod_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(k+a)^2-1}{(k+a)^2+b^2}=\prod_{k=0}^\infty\left(1-\frac{b^2+1}{(k+a)^2+b^2}\right).
$$

Answer (score 0):

- In general, expressible in terms of the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).
- For $a\in$ **N**, expressible in terms of the $($hyperbolic or trigonometric$)$ [sine function$($s$)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem).
- For $a=n+\dfrac12$, with $n\in$ **N**, expressible in terms of the $($hyperbolic or trigonometric$)$ cosine function$($s$)$.

Comment: What's the solution for case (ii)? I think I can then extend it to the most general case.